# PHP - Divide sequence of numbers by decimal separation

Tags: php

I have a number that represents a software version (ex: 1.2.0.14) and I need to separate each number that is divided by a decimal and store each number as a separate variable.

Example:

Original number is 1.2.0.14

```
$current_version_major = 1;
$current_version_minor = 2;
$current_version_revision = 0;
$current_version_build = 14;
```

What would be the most efficient way to go about doing this?

Comment: If that is your actual use case, you might also consider [`version_compare`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) or one of the alternatives mentioned there.

Comment: I tried Sarfraz's example and it worked well, but I wasn't aware of version_compare(), works a lot easier then what I came up with.  Submit this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't actually need to store the version fields separately and just want to compare two versions, then [`version_compare`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) is sometimes a good alternative:

```
switch (version_compare("1.2.0.14", "1.2.0.22")) {
    case -1:  // second version number is higher
    case  0:  // both identical
    case +1:  // second version is older
}
```

Besides supporting some text gimmicks (`rc` and `beta` suffixes) version_compare evaluates each part as integer, so that `.14` is interpreted newer than `.2`. It also works with patch suffixes `1.0-2`

It's even easier to use `version_compare("2.0", "1.0", ">")` to get a boolean result.

Comment: This is a good example of why askers should mention what their objective is, instead of just asking about an implementation detail along the way.

Answer (score 6):

> I need to separate each number that is
>   divided by a decimal and store each
>   number as a separate variable.

The best you can do is to use `explode` and `list` like this:

```
list(
      $current_version_major,
      $current_version_minor,
      $current_version_revision,
      $current_version_build) = explode('.', $version_number);
```

**More Info:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
- http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_array_list.asp

Answer (score 2):

```
list($current_version_major,$current_version_minor,$current_version_revision,$current_version_build) = explode('.',$version);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
$version = explode(".", "1.2.0.14");
```

Now `$version[0]` contains "1" for major. `$version[1]` contains "2" for minor, `$version[2]` contains "0" for revision, and `$version[3]` contains "14" for build.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has an [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function which returns you the elements as an array where delimiter will be "." (your 'decimal').